# Compare JS object key to see if it's the same TypeScript type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Imagine this scenario of code:

```
type A = {
  keyOne: string;
  keyTwo: string;
};

type B = {
  keyThree: string;
  keyFour: string;
};

type C = {
  unionKey: A | B;
  keyFive: string;
};

type CA = {
  unionKey: A;
  keyFive: string;
};

type CB = {
  unionKey: B;
  keyFive: string;
};

const obj: C = {} as C;

if ('keyOne' in obj.unionKey) {
  obj.unionKey.
}

const handleType = (obj: C): CA | CB => {
  if ('keyOne' in obj.unionKey) {
    return obj as CA;
  } else return obj as CB;
};

const result = handleType({
  unionKey: {
    keyThree: 'sdfsd',
    keyFour: 'sadfasd',
  },
  keyFive: 'sdfsd',
});

result.unionKey. // TS is get confused here and could not suggest me correct type which I'm looking for (keyThree & keyFour)
```

Consider having `obj`, how can I check the type on `unionKey` to see which type it follows? If it is type `A` I want to do work X, and if it is `B` I want to do work Y.

The issue is the comparing JS value to TS type!

Comment: Typescript uses duck typing, testing for instanceOf has no effect here, but what you can do it check the the key,  `if ('keyOne' in obj.unionKey) {}`

Comment: thanks for reply, what if i want to have a function that would check specifically for this, like if it detects the `keyOne` in `obj` returns the object in  ```type C = { unionKey: A; keyFive: string; };``` or the other way around. 
I want not to to the casting for this, is there a clean way of doing so you think?

Comment: There should be no casting involved, if you do `if ('keyOne' in obj.unionKey) { obj.unionKey.keyOne } //will be valid` but `keyThree` will not.  An alternative if you want to use instanceof, you will need to use classes, not just plain objects and types.

Comment: just updated the question to explain a bit more what am i looking for. I want a function that would return the correct type based on value that i'm feeding to it

Comment: Why not `<T extends CA | CB>(obj: T): T => ...`? I think a generic would do the trick.

Comment: i actually dont want to pass generic to the function, i want function to detects which type it is and returns it to me

Comment: You don't have to pass a generic, typescript will infer, I'll post an answer showing this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to use a generic type, and the type will fall pass.

eg..

```
function handleType<T extends C>(obj: T) {
  if ('keyOne' in obj.unionKey) {
    return obj;
  } else return obj;
};
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=3&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUDWEQHkB2EAXFAM7ABOAlngOYDcam2AKgO4D2xZVtDAvgxShIUAEIJkjLCGYALchCKkK1elOwAxdgFdyXFbxQCUQ8NADCE1Om15K7PAGlsxOAB8xDdNI2UAbkrcqvyCAGa2AMbA9nhQsgCGeAAmADYQzGYAPMxQEAAewBDJJFDmAHwAFOwARgBWxMwAlJLolKFQFQDk0vgQnVDUUDW1AHS2Mc4gzdboUArAurHDXlB8uSkk0POLQ3UhJhEOZHMQJNopwBIJyWkZkBUz4w6TxDPeLPKKxJ0kSaG-nQANIx3iAtLpviR4n94gDgeg%20PCmGD-Eofn84UZGoIFGcLmM7M9sCMfDpyHQoAB6SnsDBAA)